# Validate ABI JSon (Ethereum)

Tags: json, validation, abi, ethereum

i've a problem with the following Json :

```
[ { constant: false,
inputs: [Object],
    name: 'set',
    outputs: [],
    type: 'function'
}, {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'get',
    outputs: [Object],
    type: 'function'
}, {
    anonymous: false,
    inputs: [Object],
    name: 'ItBlinks',
    type: 'event'
},
    set: {
        [Function: bound]
        request: [Function: bound],
        call: [Function: bound],
        sendTransaction: [Function: bound],
        estimateGas: [Function: bound],
        getData: [Function: bound],
        uint256: [Circular]
    },
    get: {
        [Function: bound]
        request: [Function: bound],
        call: [Function: bound],
        sendTransaction: [Function: bound],
        estimateGas: [Function: bound],
        getData: [Function: bound],
        '': [Circular]
    },
    allEvents: [Function: bound],
    ItBlinks: {
        [Function: bound] uint256: [Function: bound]
    }
}
```

This JSon is the ABI and this should be add to my contract into my wallet (Ethereum Wallet) to send information (in this case, made a blink event on my raspberry PI)

When I add these line into my contract in my ethereum wallet, it tell me my Json is not correct.

I've try to validate, but it give me an error, and i cannot solve it. (I'm a beginner in JSon)

Somebody can help me to validate the get / set method? to be a valid JSon format?

This is the full return with coinbase (the address and coinbase is modified) :

```
coinbase : 0x20408a19c567a475545947600a95130f24f7C123
{ _eth:
   Eth {
     _requestManager: { provider: [Object], polls: {}, timeout: null },
     getBalance: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getBalance' },
     getStorageAt: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getStorageAt' },
     getCode: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getCode' },
     getBlock: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: [Function] },
     getUncle: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: [Function] },
     getCompilers: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getCompilers' },
     getBlockTransactionCount: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: [Function] },
     getBlockUncleCount: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: [Function] },
     getTransaction:
      { [Function]
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'eth_getTransactionByHash' },
     getTransactionFromBlock: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: [Function] },
     getTransactionReceipt:
      { [Function]
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'eth_getTransactionReceipt' },
     getTransactionCount: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getTransactionCount' },
     call: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_call' },
     estimateGas: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_estimateGas' },
     sendRawTransaction: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_sendRawTransaction' },
     signTransaction: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_signTransaction' },
     sendTransaction: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_sendTransaction' },
     sign: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_sign' },
     compile: { solidity: [Object], lll: [Object], serpent: [Object] },
     submitWork: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_submitWork' },
     getWork: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getWork' },
     coinbase: [Getter],
     getCoinbase: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ] },
     mining: [Getter],
     getMining: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ] },
     hashrate: [Getter],
     getHashrate: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ] },
     syncing: [Getter],
     getSyncing: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ] },
     gasPrice: [Getter],
     getGasPrice: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ] },
     accounts: [Getter],
     getAccounts: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ] },
     blockNumber: [Getter],
     getBlockNumber: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ] },
     protocolVersion: [Getter],
     getProtocolVersion: { [Function] request: [Function: bound ] },
     iban:
      { [Function]
        fromAddress: [Function],
        fromBban: [Function],
        createIndirect: [Function],
        isValid: [Function] },
     sendIBANTransaction: [Function: bound ] },
  transactionHash: null,
  address: '0x9535eb707582edb3317dfdcdb365ce4186500C123',
  abi:
   [ { constant: false,
       inputs: [Object],
       name: 'set',
       outputs: [],
       type: 'function' },
     { constant: true,
       inputs: [],
       name: 'get',
       outputs: [Object],
       type: 'function' },
     { anonymous: false,
       inputs: [Object],
       name: 'ItBlinks',
       type: 'event' } ],
  set:
   { [Function: bound ]
     request: [Function: bound ],
     call: [Function: bound ],
     sendTransaction: [Function: bound ],
     estimateGas: [Function: bound ],
     getData: [Function: bound ],
     uint256: [Circular] },
  get:
   { [Function: bound ]
     request: [Function: bound ],
     call: [Function: bound ],
     sendTransaction: [Function: bound ],
     estimateGas: [Function: bound ],
     getData: [Function: bound ],
     '': [Circular] },
  allEvents: [Function: bound ],
  ItBlinks: { [Function: bound ] uint256: [Function: bound ] } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have valid JSON. JSON has key/value pairs with keys being strings delimited by double quotes. Details of JSON can be found [here](http://www.json.org/)

From the Ethereum documentation this is an example of JSON in the ABI:

```
[{
"type":"event",
"inputs": [{"name":"a","type":"uint256","indexed":true},
{"name":"b","type":"bytes32","indexed":false}],
"name":"Event"
}, {
"type":"event",
"inputs": [{"name":"a","type":"uint256","indexed":true},
{"name":"b","type":"bytes32","indexed":false}],
"name":"Event2"
}, {
"type":"event",
"inputs": [{"name":"a","type":"uint256","indexed":true},
{"name":"b","type":"bytes32","indexed":false}],
"name":"Event2"
}, {
"type":"function",
"inputs": [{"name":"a","type":"uint256"}],
"name":"foo",
"outputs": []
}]
```

Details of the ethereum contract ABI can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI)

Answer (score 1):

What you were showing is a payload from coinbase it contains lots of information regarding your request, the smart-contracts ABI is one of them.

In reality it is only
`abi:[ { constant: false,
       inputs: [Object],
       name: 'set',
       outputs: [],
       type: 'function' },
     { constant: true,
       inputs: [],
       name: 'get',
       outputs: [Object],
       type: 'function' },
     { anonymous: false,
       inputs: [Object],
       name: 'ItBlinks',
       type: 'event' } ]`

you can access the abi by doing this

`coinbase[0x20408a19c567a475545947600a95130f24f7C123].abi`

i don't know your exact use case but i suggest you read about smart contracts abis [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI)

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same issue.

The problem is this [Object] inside your JSON

You probably get the ABI from console.log object.

You have to convert this JSON object to a string, and then console.log it and grab the output which will be a valid JSON.